# How does an NFT marketplace give a verified badge?

Tags: nft, erc-721, storage, database, opensea

I am trying to build an NFT marketplace. I see that Opensea provides a verifiable account badge. Here is the link for [documentation](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360063519133-What-is-a-verified-account-or-collection-)

I wonder how Opensea uniquely identifies the user if it is qualified for the badge. What data do they store and where do they store it?

Since everything around blockchain applications should be decentralized, I believe a central database would not make sense because an admin can manually give a badge to any user.

Answer (score 0):

NFT marketplaces are not decentralized.

What happens when people start hosting [CENSORED: something horrible was here] on your website?

Or what about if someone just plain steals Metallica copyrighted music for sale on your website?

These both require human review. And you can handle this by normal web 2 means.

If you are willing to created badges and share this information publicly and by Web3, that's great! Just make an NFT and give this out to every collection you have manually verified.